# How to return last emitted value from observable with late subscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Consider the following code snippet

```
const interval$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).share();

interval$.subscribe(x=> console.log('a=' + a));

setTimeout(() => {
    interval$.subscribe(x=> console.log('b=' + b));
}, 1500);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8zk4ovxc/261/)

I need the late subscriber to also return the last emitted value (which is 0 in this case). How can this be done with RxJS (Note I need a shared observable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a shared observable that replays the last emitted value to late subscribers, replace:

```
const interval$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .share();
```

with:

```
const interval$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();
```

`share` is similar to `.publish().refCount()`, so if you want to replay the last emitted value, [`publishReplay`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publishReplay) is what you could use instead.